# No me funciona un script en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código, funciona muy bien la parte de `css` y `html5`, pero no logro saber porqué no se ejecuta el `script` ,  desde el botón llamo a la función `verificación();` mediante el evento `onclick`, pero al presionar el botón pasa absolutamente nada.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>algo</title>
<link href="../css/tarea_sesion14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script>

function verificacion(){
var numero1;
numero1 = document.getElementById("CajaTexto1").value;
if(isNaN(numero1)){
    alert("No escribiste un numero");
}else{
    if(numero1>=1 && numero1<=6){
        for(var i=0: i>numero1: i++){
            document.write("Esta es la vez numero "+i+" que se ejecuta el 
for");
        }
    }else{
        alert("Favor de escribir en la caja de texto un numero entre el 1 y el 6");
    }
 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="contenedor">

<div id="izquierdo">
</div>

<div id="principal">
    <fieldset>
    <form id="formularioTarea14" name="form1" method="post">
        <label >Escribe un numero del 1 al 6:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CajaTexto1">
        <input type="submit" onclick="verificacion();" id="btn_ejecutar" value="Iniciar">
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se trata de un error de Sintaxis en el `for` no se aceptan los dos puntos para separar las partes de un `for`

```
 /* Incorrecto los : */
for(inicializacion: condición :  incremento o decre){...}
/* Correcto el ; */
for(inicializacion; condición ;  incremento o decre){...}
```

si modifica su `for` con esto  , no debería tener errores de sintaxis **pero si** de `lógica` en la condición del `for` ya que no ejecutará nunca lo que se encuentra dentro.

```
Si ingresa 4 , pregunta  0 > 4  /* retorna false*/
Si ingresa 4 , pregunta  0 > 4  /* retorna false*/
```

Su código final sería

```js
function verificacion(){
  var numero1 = document.getElementById("CajaTexto1").value;
  if(isNaN(numero1))  alert("No escribiste un numero");
  else{
    if(numero1>=1 && numero1<=6){
        for(var i=0; i<numero1; i++)
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += "Esta es la vez numero "+(i+1)+" que se ejecuta el for <br>";
    }
    else alert("Favor de escribir en la caja de texto un numero entre el 1 y el 6");
   }
   return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="CajaTexto1">
<input type="submit" onclick="verificacion();" id="btn_ejecutar" value="Iniciar">
<div id="resultado">
 
</div>
```

Tener cuidado sobre el `type` del `botón` ya que se enviará el `form` , para solucionar esto añadí el `return false` para que no se ejecute el envio, sobre `document.write` que en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/write) hay una nota Importante.

> Nota: dado que `document.write` escribe directo al hilo (stream) de un
>   documento, la llamada a document.write en un documento ya cargado
>   automáticamente ejecuta `document.open`, **lo cual limpiará todo el
>   contenido del documento en cuestión.**

Comment: Gracias, en lo correcto era la Sintaxis del for.

Comment: Yo pense que eran las llaves mucho if

Comment: @Victor-Random si es muy confuso tanta apertura y cierre de llaves por eso prefiero no colocar llaves **cuando solo hay una línea de código dentro de una estructura.**

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios errores.
El primero, en el bucle `for` separas las propiedades con '`:`' en vez de '`;`'
Después, el bucle lo realizas mientras `i>numero1` y debería ser mientras que `i<numero1`
Otro problema, el botón es del tipo `submit` por lo que recargará la página, para que solo ejecute la función debería ser de tipo `button`.
Más cosas, el método `document.write` borra la página si se usa una vez cargada, como es el caso al usarla en un `button`, usa otro sistema para mostrar los datos, como incrementar el `innerHTML` de algún elemento.
Cosas menores, para que el mensaje no se escriba seguido añade un salto al final, y si quieres que muestre un contador iniciando en 1, deberás mostarlo sumando 1, ya que realmente inicia con 0. La llamada a la función no hace falta que termine con `;`

Una vez corregido queda algo parecido a esto:

```js
function verificacion(){
var numero1;
numero1 = document.getElementById("CajaTexto1").value;
if(isNaN(numero1)){
    alert("No escribiste un numero");
}else{
    if(numero1>=1 && numero1<=6){
        for(var i=0; i<numero1; i++){
            document.documentElement.innerHTML+=("Esta es la vez numero "+(i+1)+" que se ejecuta el for<br>");
        }
    }else{
        alert("Favor de escribir en la caja de texto un numero entre el 1 y el 6");
    }
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>algo</title>
<link href="../css/tarea_sesion14.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="contenedor">

<div id="izquierdo">
</div>

<div id="principal">
    <fieldset>
    <form id="formularioTarea14" name="form1" method="post">
        <label >Escribe un numero del 1 al 6:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CajaTexto1">
        <input type="button" onclick="verificacion()" id="btn_ejecutar" value="Iniciar">
    </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```